# Apache Directory Studio “Failed to load JNI shared library”

Tags: java, apache, directory

I have ApacheDS 64 bits, Java JRE 7 64bits, Windows 7 64bits and (because I need) java 1.5 JDK  and I continue with the same error. What can I do?

Java -version brings:

java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You must have the same version of java and your aplication, for example: 
- java 64bit
- apacheDS 64bit

If it does not work, download fresh java JKD from Oracle and reinstall it, then reinstall ApacheDS. It worked for me after.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need a higher java version to launch the Apache Directory Studio.
So modify your JAVA_HOME to the jdk1.8

After that, configure your environment to the jdk1.5, but just inside your IDE.